# What happens when I copy a card with awaken?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-awaken

If I copy [Part the Waterveil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPart%20the%20Waterveil%5d) for which I pay 6UUU with [Mirrorpool](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMirrorpool%5d), do I get to turn one or two lands into creatures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The awakened version of Part the Waterveil targets a land; since Mirrorpool's ability says "You may choose new targets for the copy." you can choose either the same land or another land. As @Arthur says in the comments, it should be noted that the copy is also awakened, since that is an alternative cost:

> 702.112a Awaken appears on some instants and sorceries. It represents two abilities: a static ability that functions while the spell with awaken is on the stack and a spell ability. “Awaken N—[cost]” means “You may pay [cost] rather than pay this spell’s mana cost as you cast this spell” and “If this spell’s awaken cost was paid, put N +1/+1 counters on target land you control. That land becomes a 0/0 Elemental creature with haste. It’s still a land.” Paying a spell’s awaken cost follows the rules for paying alternative costs in rules 601.2b and 601.2f–h.

and that information is copied as well:

> 706.10. To copy a spell, activated ability, or triggered ability means to put a copy of it onto the stack; a copy of a spell isn’t cast and a copy of an activated ability isn’t activated. A copy of a spell or ability copies both the characteristics of the spell or ability and all decisions made for it, including modes, targets, the value of X, and additional or alternative costs.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to address the fact that the copied spell is indeed awakened.